# UISlider - IB_DESIGNABLE - runtime attribute warning

Tags: swift, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I am trying to render a vertical slider in interface builder however, when I try to set the value interface builder gives me a warning.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
@IBDesignable
class VerticalSlider: UISlider {

    @IBInspectable var setOrientation: Bool! {
        didSet {

            if setOrientation == true{

                self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI_2))

            }else {

                self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

            }

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@IBInspectable` property `setOrientation` shouldn't be an implicitly unwrapped optional, just a non-optional boolean property.

If you change the declaration of `setOrientation` to a regular (non-optional) boolean with a default (initial) value, say `false`, you should no longer be prompted with warnings regarding your `@IBInspectable`.

```
@IBInspectable var setOrientation: Bool = false { ... }
```